# ruby on rails web development using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

my app is not been uploaded on

> heroku

only the first page with welcome to ruby on rails is displayed
my url is
[my url link](http://polar-anchorage-3723.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deployed app is presently being overridden by Rails' default static index page. From `config/routes.rb`:

```
# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# just remember to delete public/index.html.
```

Therefore, first ensure that your root route is set:

```
# config/routes.rb
root :to => `root_controller#root_action`
```

Then, delete `public/index.html`, commit the changes to version control, and redeploy to Heroku.

Comment: the problem is if i already have the repositary the how to delete it in the git hub

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have correct routes. Then you commit the changes to the master branch and then:

```
git push heroku master
```

Hope this helps.